# Kotlin same map same Object by multiple keys

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of objects that looks like:

```
data class Student(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val gpa: Long,
        val age: Int
)
```

I wanna have 2 maps:

1. `student.name` -> `Student`
2. `student.id` -> `Student`

But I don't wanna duplicate the maps.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

I've tried to map `Student.id`->`Student.name` and use this but wanted to be sure there is no standard solution already exists for that in Kotlin.

Thanks

Comment: You want to map a list of students and get a list of students with only `id` and `name` as properties, correct?

Comment: No, I wanna get the complete object of Each student by it's Id or it's name

Comment: this does not sound like a good idea. Are the names even guaranteed to be unique? one name can always just map to one Student, but what if there are two students with the same name? that's why you use a generated unique ID as identifier.

Comment: It sounds weird, I know.
But the names are guaranteed to be unique

Comment: If you have a list of students you could just filter it by using `listOfStudents.filter { it.id == <searched-id> || it.name == <searched-name> }`. If this is what you need.

Comment: But the list is huge.
I dont wanna filter it every time i need to find a student. I need a random access solution

Comment: First of all: this sounds like a problem the database should handle ;)
Secondly: What's the problem with 2 maps? It's not like the object is duplicated because Kotlin just stores the references to the objects anyway.
Other than that I don't think you can work around having two maps or just `students.first { it.id == id }` (or with `name`) it.

Comment: If you map the ID to a name, then you have two maps anyway, and the second map will take up just as much memory as a version where you map the `id` directly to the `Student` because both maps can point at the same Student instances.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, just make two maps. That's what you want anyway - you have two mappings, `id` to `Student` and `name` to `Student`. You need a map for each.

Those properties just happen to be stored in the `Student` object - but imagine if they weren't, would you mind having two maps then? One for `separateIdentifier1` to `Student`, and one for `separateIdentifier2` to `Student`? That would be fine, right - it's just what you have to do!

And if you only had one of those embedded properties, like `student.id` - would you say "I don't want to make a map because that attribute is already stored in the data"? No, you'd still make the map, right? Because you're not storing data, you're creating a fast lookup that's generated from that data. And it's exactly the same principle if you're creating two or more lookups. And you're not duplicating the objects, just adding an entry of `object reference` to `object reference`

Really you just want to generate derived maps, where your actual data is the collection of `Student` objects, and the mappings for `id` and `name` are just automatically generated. You need to ensure that when (if) you add or remove a `Student`, that both mappings get updated, and that those updates happen together, atomically. Handle concurrency if you need to, that kind of thing.

There's nothing like that in the Kotlin standard library, which is more focused on core functional components you can bolt together into more specialised things. I can't see anything similar in Guava either - they have `MultiMap`s (one key to many values) and `Table`s (a pair of keys to a single value) but nothing where you have multiple keys that can be used interchangeably. Just roll your own I reckon!